# CSS Alternative of tabindex

Tags: html, css

I was wondering if there is any CSS alternative of tabindex.

```html
<button tabindex="1">ONE</button>
<button tabindex="3">TWO</button>
<button tabindex="2">THREE</button>
```

The alternative [`nav-index`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-ui-3/#nav-index0) has been long dropped.

> The following features are at-risk, and may be dropped during the CR period:
>
> Directional focus navigation: the nav-up, nav-right, nav-down, nav-left properties.

Comment: Any reason you want to do this?

Comment: Yes I am trying to make the page keyboard accessible

Comment: Whats wrong with `tabindex` ?

Comment: I am trying to override few tab index value without javascript

Comment: Buttons are already keyboard accessible, as a general rule, assigning any value other than 0 (or -1 for scripting support of focus) is going to do more harm than good.

Comment: @steveax This is just a example snippet. I am trying to figure out a way for the complete webpage

Comment: Go for JavaScript solution

Comment: @shubhamagrawal there are more important things to look at if you're looking at making a website accessible. Read this https://webaccess.berkeley.edu/resources/tips/web-accessibility

Comment: @Mr.Alien that means there is no CSS alternative

Answer (score 1):

The order of the items on the page is the only other way to determine tab index order. This is what I used to do years ago when I had to support non-javascript versions of a website. What you can do with css is then reposition the items visually, and nowadays you have the advantage of using flex, and order.

```
<style type="text/css">
.myFlexWrapper{
   display:flex; 
   /* I advise using sass and autoprefixer to poly fill all the other browsers*/
}

.myFlexWrapper button:nth-child(1){
  order:30; /* will display this button visually last but retain the tabindex as 1 because it's the first item.*/
}
.myFlexWrapper button:nth-child(2){
  order:10;/* will display this button visually first but retain the tabindex as 2 because it's the second item.*/
}
.myFlexWrapper button:nth-child(3){
  order:20;/* will display this button visually second but retain the tabindex as 3 because it's the third item.*/
}
</style>

<div class="myFlexWrapper">
   <button>ONE</button>
   <button>TWO</button>
   <button>THREE</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can simply prevent the tab event by following CSS :

button:focus {
  display:none
}

This will prevent the tab event on the button

Comment: Unfortunately this will also change the layout.

Comment: This definitely does not work for me to disable tab on an input :(